# angularJS | Javascript - regex replace

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I need to remove a substring that looks like this

> page/*number*/

I think the regex goes like this: `"page/[0-9]+/"` (correct me if I'm wrong).

Is this the correct way?

```
"www.myurl/archive/page/25/?abc=xyz".replace(page/[0-9]+/,"");
```

Or is there something I'm missing?

**EDIT:

Whoever votes -1, can you comment the reason so that I'll know for the next time I ask a question? Thanks**

Comment: Declare the pattern in the form of a string literal and pass it to the RegExp constructor.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Why that rather than using literal notation? People get really confused by the double-escaping required in the string form...

Comment: Because there are `/`. You do not need to escape them in a constructor notation.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: True enough. This *particular* regex doesn't have the double-escape problem with the string constructor. (I knew you had a reason.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Or is there something I'm missing?

Delimiters. :-) You need delimters around the regular expression so the JavaScript parser knows it's a regular expression. (And since it happens those delimiters are `/`, you need to escape the `/` inside the regex with a backslash.)

```js
var result = "www.myurl/archive/page/25/?abc=xyz".replace(/page\/[0-9]+\//, "");
console.log(result);
```

Note that that will also change `www.myurl/archive/blahpage/25/?abc=xyz` (note `blahpage` rather than `page`). If you only want to replace `/page/`, we want another (escaped) `/` at the beginning and we want to replace the old thing with `"/"` rather than `""`:

```
var result = "www.myurl/archive/page/25/?abc=xyz".replace(/\/page\/[0-9]+\//, "/");
```

...unless this is always just prior to the `?`, in which case the trailing `/` isn't needed and we could keep using `""`). Here it is assuming this will always be followed by the `?`:

```
var result = "www.myurl/archive/page/25/?abc=xyz".replace(/\/page\/[0-9]+\//, "");
```

```js
var result = "www.myurl/archive/page/25/?abc=xyz".replace(/\/page\/[0-9]+\//, "");
console.log(result);
```

Comment: @Rizwan: The OP's code didn't have the `/` before `page`, which is why it wasn't in the regex I posted in the answer. I appreciate the attempt to help, but it's important to respect the author's intent when editing. Thanks again anyway. (I'll add a note for the OP about optionally adding it.)